# Nginx: Redirect subdomain to path

Tags: nginx, rewrite

This is very similar to the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491944/nginx-convert-subdomain-to-path-component-without-redirect,

however I need it to be a permanent redirect (not proxy), and the subdomain can be one of about 15 different things. The solution from the question above looks like this

```
# abc.example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name abc.example.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com/abc$request_uri permanent;
}

# example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location / { 
    # ...
  }
}
```

But I need `abc` to be available in a variable. The `server_name` will simply be a list of all 15 possibilities.

Thanks

Comment: Server_name could be regexp. See nginx doc

Comment: Yeah I realise that, I just want to restrict it down to the preset list though

Comment: So you have problem with writing regexp that match 15 distinct strings?

Comment: No, I have a problem passing the a sub domain value into the path, when the sub domain can change.

Comment: Have you really read docs?

Comment: Yes, however you're more than welcome to point me to the appropriate bit of the documentation for this scenario.

Comment: `server_name ^(?<sub>aaa|bbb|ccc)\.example\.com$; return 301 http://example.com/$sub$request_uri;`